# How to simulate accident in Anylogic personal learning edition

Tags: anylogic, traffic-simulation

Using the road traffic library in Anylogic, how do i simulate an occasional accident, a sensor notification to a response team, a rescue by response team and giving road access priority to response team traffic routing out of the scene

Answer (score 0):

The road traffic library is probably not the best choice for this. You will need to use the process modeling library since it may be better for this application. But if you are using the road traffic library no matter what, here are some ideas:

- The way you can simulate an accidente is setting the speed of the cars to 0... But you will have to create your own logic to make this happen (maybe using stop lines)... For visual help you can change how the car looks like to some car in flames or something.
- The notification to the response team you can do it on your own... using statecharts, or something else... this is the easy part of your project
- You can't give road priority access directly... but what you can do is to use an intersection instead of a road. Since in the intersection you can define lanes that can be used or not.

Nevertheless the big problem with your question is that it is a design question, and not something specific. So I can just give you some ideas, but not resolve the question completely.

Comment: An insightful response

Comment: Let me present the full picture and get professional advice if anylogic simulation is the way to go on this task

RESOURCES INVOLVED
Car/Vehicle/Ambulance, Rescue team, Control room,GPS,GSM, Micro controller, Sensors, Traffic control system

SEQUENCE
Vehicle accident occurs
Sensors detect accident

Comment: GPS and GSM receive signals from sensors
GPS and GSM signal control room with alert
Control room gets data and locates the nearest available ambulance and hospital (best route)
Ambulance gets alert from control room on accident
Ambulance alert control room of its availability
Control room finds next available ambulance
Ambulance heads to accident scene
Control room for shortest available route to nearest hospital
Control room signals all traffic light for access
Ambulance gets to hospital and notifies control room of arrival
Ambulance is available for next assignment

Comment: You can do it in AnyLogic yes.. a combination of traffic library and agent-based would be my first guess... or second choice would be just to use process modeling library without the road traffic library

Comment: Been trying to simulate the entire process as advised but great challenges lay ahead
As a novice in Anylogic, a crush course by a guru will do
How do i dm/pm or contact you to gain your personal attention